# Jenkins pipeline credentials single vs double quotes interpolation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm getting this `Warning: A secret was passed to "httpRequest" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure` using the first example here. I made this `keyvar = credentials('key_id')` as an environmental variable and put it in something like this

```
 def response = httpRequest url: "https://url...", 
           customHeaders: [[name: 'Authorization', value: "${keyvar}"]]...
```

Which works but is not how it should be properly done as described in this [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation), so following that I tried what it suggested here, using single quotes and no bracket.

```
 def response = httpRequest url: "https://url...", 
           customHeaders: [[name: 'Authorization', value: '$keyvar']]...
```

This solves the first error but now I get `Response Code: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` which to me, means that interpolation isn't working within the single quotes as the documentation describes.

Comment: The documentation states that the environment variable interpolates inside the shell interpreter when passed as an argument to a shell step method. You are passing it as an argument to a `httpRequest` method. Try passing the argument directly to the argument without recasting as a string, but the method may not support secrets redaction in the output either.

Comment: That'll do it. Thank you @MattSchuchard

Comment: Oh I see now you were passing the secret into the `customHeaders` Map argument for `httpRequest`, so I think that does actually obscure the secret for you.

Answer (score 4):

To make the answer from Matt Schuchard in the comments more clear for future people stumbling upon this - you need to *remove the string interpolation* and pass the variable directly:

```
 def response = httpRequest url: "https://url...", 
           customHeaders: [[name: 'Authorization', value: keyvar]]...
```

This also works for headers that require an additional prefix (e.g. `Bearer`):

```
 def response = httpRequest url: "https://url...", 
           customHeaders: [[name: 'Authorization', value: 'Bearer ' + keyvar]]...
```

is safe, while

```
 def response = httpRequest url: "https://url...", 
           customHeaders: [[name: 'Authorization', value: "Bearer $keyvar"]]...
```

is not.

Comment: This is the key to resolving this for the `httpRequest` step indeed. The Jenkins documentation conveniently only mentions the `sh` step which has access to the environment variables anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of httpRequest method, I have the aliOssUpload method. It doesn’t work by passing the argument directly to the argument without recasting as a string.

Comment: Can you provide some documentation for the aliOssUpload method? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The interpolation warning can be resolved by escaping the `$\keyvar`